# How to display mock data in html in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, mocking, display

I have created mock service file and I want to display in my html but not really sure how to make it display properly so I'll be really appreciated If I can get any help or suggestion.

```
<div class="container2">
  <div class="header" style="height: 400px">
    <div class="content3">
      <div>
        <h1 class="kpi-title">90,346</h1>.     // I'm trying to remove this hard code html
        <p class="kpi-des">Users Right Now</p> // and display it from my mock data file.
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1 class="kpi-title">250++l</h1>
        <p class="kpi-des">Saved</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1 class="kpi-title">$34.5 mill</h1>
        <p class="kpi-des">New User per Week</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

TS

```
import { ProductService } from '../../data/product-suite.service';

export class MaxisProductSuiteComponent {
  productService: ProductService[];

ngOnIT(){
}
```

product-suite.service.ts

```
export class ProductService {
  productsuite: ProductSuite[] = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: '90,346',
      description: 'Users',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: '$34.5 mill',
      description: 'Saved',
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: '250++',
      description: 'New User per Week',
    },
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the below code for your solutions:

1. create a json file assets folder with name output.json.

   ```
    {
    "result" : [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "90,346",
            "description": "Users at Ford"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "$34.5 mill",
            "description": "Saved for Ford"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "250++",
            "description": "New User per Week"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "title": "64%",
            "description": "Users At Ford"
        }
    ]
   ```

   }
2. in service file write below code:

```
    import { observable, Observable } from "rxjs";
    import { MaxisProductSuite } from "src/Model/model";
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'; 
    import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
    
    @Injectable()
    export class MaxisProductService {
      constructor(private http: HttpClient){}
    
      getAllMaxisps():Observable<MaxisProductSuite> {
        return this.http.get<MaxisProductSuite>("./assets/output.json");
      }
    }
```

3. then component file add below code:

```
    import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
    import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { MaxisProductSuite } from 'src/Model/model';
    import { MaxisProductService } from 'src/service/MaxisProductService';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-temp',
      templateUrl: './temp.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./temp.component.scss']
    })
    export class TempComponent implements OnInit {
       maxisps: MaxisProductSuite[];
       public resultData:MaxisProductSuite=null;
    
      constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document, private service : MaxisProductService) {}
    
      ngOnInit() {
        this.service.getAllMaxisps().subscribe((res:MaxisProductSuite) => {
         console.log(res);
         this.resultData =res;
        });    
      }
    
    }
```

4. then HTMl file add below code:

   ```
    <div *ngFor="let item of resultData?.result">
    <div class="header" style="height: 400px">
      <h1>{{item.id}}</h1>
      <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
      <h3>{{item.description}}</h3>
    </div>
   ```
5. add below model in model file

```
    export interface MaxisProductSuite {
        result : Result[]
      }
    
      export interface Result{
        id?: number;
        title: string;
        description: string;
      }
```

I hope it will help you to get the solution.

happy to HELP!

Answer (score 0):

1. make your service in module provider or make it injectable "root".
2. inject the service in your component you want to display data in constructor as a dependency injection.
3. assign your component variable array with `productService`.
4. in your HTML loop about your data array using `*ngFor=" let product of products"`.
5. use you product value in the interpolation `{{ product.id }}`.